# Sum of a number for each element in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, sum, redux

I am working in a redux function where i want for each element in array the sum with n number

This is the code

```
let neWd = array.map(x => {
  if (x === 'M' || x === 'L'){
    return x;
  }else{
    return x + 5;
  }
}).join(' ')
```

At the moment `return x + 5` is adding the `5` number to any element of the array but not the sum.

How can i achieve it?

Comment: which sum? please add the array as well.

Comment: What is the "SUM" ? Your question is unclear.

Comment: Give us input array and expected array

Comment: Are you looking for `array.reduce`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have a string and it is splitted with `' '` and then you get each element as string. You need to cast it to a number, in this example with an unary `+` for incrementing with `5`.

This proposal splits on white space, which can be more than one characters long.

```js
var string = 'M 175 0  L 326.55444566227675 87.50000000000001  L 326.55444566227675 262.5  L 175 350  L 23.445554337723223 262.5  L 23.44555433772325 87.49999999999999 L 175 0',
    array = string.split(/\s+/),
    result = array.map(x => x === 'M' || x === 'L' ? x : +x + 5).join(' ');

console.log(result);
```

Comment: the path d was exactly the array i want to manipulate :)

Comment: there is a little problem, with an array like [M 175 0  L 326] this is now the result [M 180 5 5 1 L 331]

Comment: i get the right result, please see above.

Comment: you are right and i accept the answer but i am doing smth wrong with the same code https://gist.github.com/Mannaio/8360930e848c47edcdcfa85c0af8cedb

Comment: can you add the original string?

Comment: do you have some numbers, which should not change?

Comment: yes sure, this is the original string https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4ea14b1556e10d402330cceab9be3986

Comment: your string has some more white space inside the string. so a space became the value 5. i changed the splitting part for dynamic whitespace.